# FTOC with one indefinite boundary

Tags: calculus

For any function $u$, is it possible to write using FTOC
\begin{equation}
\int_{-1}^x \partial_x u \, dx' = u(x) - u(-1)
\end{equation}

Comment: There does not appear to be any difference from the standard theorem $\int_a^bf’(t)dt =f(b)-f(a)$, so requirements for that must be met. It holds when f has a continuous derivative and also in other cases. Certainly f must be differentiable.

Comment: Assume that, $u$ is a differentiable function between [-1,1] and the upper boundary of the integral, $x$, refers to any point between this interval.

Comment: Since you have a partial derivative, the reader would assume that $u$ depends on another variable(s).  So, for example, $\int_{-1}^{x} \partial_x u(x',t) dx' = u(x,t)-u(-1,t).$

Comment: If $u$ depends another variable(s), it works. Thanks.